# Equivalent to Promise.try with Observables?

Tags: promise, rxjs, observable, bluebird

How could I start an Observable chain with a function that could potentially throw an exception and handle this exception through the observable catch mechanisms ?

Example :

```
createObservable(withFunctionThatThrowAnException())
            .catch( err => {})
            .subscribe(data => {})
```

If `withFunctionThatThrowAnException` throw an exception, observable chain as need been started yet and it's juste an uncaught exception, the observable.catch can't catch it.

With bluebird and Promises, I would have done :

```
Promise.try(() => createObservable(withFunctionThatThrowAnException()))
            .then(data => {})
            .catch(err => {})
```

Is there an equivalent with Observables ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct equivalent would be `defer`, I guess:

```
Observable.defer(() => createObservable(withFunctionThatThrowAnException()))
 .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Thanks, it perfect and oneliner ;)